# php function to check when an uploaded image has been in the directory for longer than a day

Tags: php, file-upload, controller, cron, unlink

I have a cron controller class that basically handles all cron job related work. I'm trying to add a function to the controller that deletes images that have been in the directory longer than a day. Here is what I have so far, and it makes sense to me I think, but when I test this to see if it works, I get errors such as:

**Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for 4148_1432931936_0.jpeg**

**Warning: unlink(public/images/gallery_images/files/4148_1432931936_0.jpeg**

```
public function delete_gallery_images()
{
    $dir = opendir('../public/images/gallery_images/files/');

    if ($dir) {
            // Read directory contents
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {

            if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                // Check the create time of each file (older than 1 day)
                if (filemtime($file) < (time() - 60 * 60 * 24)) {
                    unlink('../public/images/gallery_images/files/'.$file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
//      //close dir
//      closedir($dir);
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you kindly.

Comment: `public` is usually part of a server's system path and not the actual folder fetching method, such as an relative path.

Comment: Sorry I'm working locally right now, this using WAMP

Comment: you're using `../public/` but then using `unlink('public/` - when a using server system path, it's usually `/public/...`

Comment: ah you are right!! good catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have inconsistent directory names. Try this:

```
public function delete_gallery_images()
{
    $dirName = '../public/images/gallery_images/files/';
    $dir = opendir($dirName);

    if ($dir) {
            // Read directory contents
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
            if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                // Check the create time of each file (older than 1 day)
                $fname = $dirName . $file;
                if (filemtime($fname) < (time() - 60 * 60 * 24)) {
                    unlink($fname);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //close dir
    closedir($dir);
}
```